# use variable for object name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found another similar question about this with a solution but it didn't work for me. I am new to jquery so thanks in advance for helping me solve my noobie question.

I am trying to use a variable for the class name. So that I can loop through the right fields based on this variable. My variable returns `.reqfields4` but I get this error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "`, if I enter the value manually, it works.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

```
var reqsection='\".reqfields4\"';

$(".reqfields4").each ( function() { 
//$(reqsection).each ( function() {               
          if(( $(this).val())==''){
               some code...
               }
          else{
               some code...
              }
            });
```

Comment: Jquery expects a string object for a class selector, so there is absolutely no reason why you need to escape quotes here. Unless you really wanted to get a class name with a quote inside it (and it won't work, all class names start with dot and not quotemark!).The purpose of putting in quotes inside the selector is if you don't already have a string object! If your string object is in a variable, then you have your string object and that's that!. Quoting = shortcut for new String('whatever') in js, and doesn't mean something else strange or mysterious that requires quote marks for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `var reqsection='\".reqfields4\"';` to `var reqsection='.reqfields4';` - you don't need the inner string quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes inside the value of the variable:

```
var reqsection = '.reqfields4';
$(reqsection).each( ... );
```

If you have a class name — *just* a class name — you can add the `.`:

var reqsection = 'reqfields4';

$('.' + reqsection).each( ... )

Answer (score 0):

If you say `var reqsection= '\".reqfields4\"';` 
then 
`$(reqsection).each( function() {});`

Consider it like like you told jQuery this:

```
$(' ".reqfields4" ').each( function() {});
```

In other words you said: [ Please select now ".reqfields4" including the quotemarks ]. All class selectors must start with dot(.), but you just started your jQuery selector with a quotemark (") so of course it won't work at all (it won't try to select any classes, of course), and probably would throw an error from jQuery - I don't think ANY jQuery selector string can have quotemark(") as the actual first character of the selector!.

If you do this instead:

```
var reqsection= ".reqfields4";

$(".reqfields4").each( function() {});
$(reqsection).each( function() {});
```

The above two lines are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like follows,

```
var reqsection=".reqfields4";

$(reqsection).each ( function() { 

              if(( $(this).val())==''){
                   some code...
                   }
              else{
                   some code...
                  }
                });
```